# Itunes Connect - Metadata Rejected

Tags: app-store-connect

An app I submitted just got rejected because of the metadata, they specifically identified the app name as the problem. The app is for iPad only and so was named - 'My game - iPad' the iPad addition to the name seems to be the problem.

The guidelines are:

> In other words, whether appearing on the application itself and/or in marketing materials, the word iPhone may be used as a descriptor, but not as part of the product name.
>
> For example, the following are acceptable:
> GreatApp - with tagline "for iPhone"
> GreatApp - with tagline "iPhone edition"
> GreatApp - with tagline "iPhone version"
> GreatApp - with tagline "iPhone 4 for Verizon Wireless"

My question is the term tagline, there is no separate place to enter a tagline so does this mean it should be part of the app title? So my app title should be changed to 'My Game - iPad edition' or 'My Game - for iPad'?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns App Store policy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [relevant section (section 3)](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) of the review guidelines. While it doesn't mention your issue explicitly, [the App Store Marketing Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/AppStoreMarketingGuidelines.pdf) seem to allude to Apple's specific preferences regarding the use of their product names in app marketing materials.

Yes, your tag line should go in the title. No, you shouldn't have to say "for iPad". That makes a poor tag line, and the App Store does a good job at filtering results for the appropriate devices. iPhone users won't even see your app in search results. If you enjoy making redundant statements, say "for iPad" in your marketing.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the name of the app to 'My Game - iPad Edition', 'My Game for iPad', or 'My Game - iPad Version'.

They *should* accept that.